Typed Angular form with formbuilder and null as initial value
I want to make use of typed forms in Angular.
In my scenario I have a form group that should have some properties.
All of them should be nullable and start with an initial value of "null".
But they should also be typed.
I also want to use the form builder to make my code short & concise.
However, I am failing to do what I want.
One of my approaches looks like this:
   formGroup = this.fb.group<{
      User: FormControl<string | null>,
      Site: FormControl<string | null>,
      AccessLevel: FormControl<string | null>,
      Application: FormControl<string | null>,
      BusinessProcessArea: FormControl<string | null>,
    }>({
      User: [null, Validators.required],
      Site: [null, Validators.required],
      AccessLevel: [null, Validators.required],
      Application: [null, Validators.required],
      BusinessProcessArea: [null, Validators.required],
   });

However, typescript does not like what I am doing and throws an error here.
Also I need to double all the properties what makes this piece of code also hard to maintain.
I would love to do something like this:
   formGroup = this.fb.group({
      User<string>: [null, Validators.required],
      Site<string>: [null, Validators.required],
      AccessLevel<string>: [null, Validators.required],
      Application<string>: [null, Validators.required],
      BusinessProcessArea<string>: [null, Validators.required],
   });

I know that this is not valid Typescript and that I cannot put the type definition there.
But this should show my wish to:

Allow nullable fields
That are at the same time typed fields (ie: string|null)
That do not need to be repeated
That can use form builder to have a concise and clear syntax

How can I achieve this?

I find that defining an interface for my typed forms gives me a clearer syntax overall. An example is given below:

// person-form.model.ts

export interface IPersonForm {
    firstName: FormControl<string | null>;
    lastName: FormControl<string | null>;
    identifier: FormControl<string | null>;
}

// person-form.component.ts

@Component({
    selector: 'app-person-form',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [],
    templateUrl: './person-form.component.html',
    styleUrl: './person-form.component.scss',
})
export class PersonFormComponent
    implements OnInit
{
   
    private fb = inject(FormBuilder);
    public personForm!: FormGroup<IPersonForm>;

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.buildForm()
    }

    private buildForm(): void {
      this.personForm = this.fb.group({
        firstName: [null, [Validators.required]],
        lastName: [null, [Validators.required],
        identifier: [null, [Validators.maxLength(255)]],
      });
    }

       



Additionally, unless you have a specific need for null I would recommend typing the controls as string only and defining the initial value as empty string - this is a 'falsy' value and will trigger the required validator correctly without the use of null.

Interesting idea, but can you explain me one thing: If I later access a property of my form like: const myValue = this.formGroup.value.myValue, then myValue is always string|null as a type. This happens even on nonNullable form controls. Can this be avoided?

Yes, by accessing the value using a more explicit syntax: this.formGroup.controls.controlName.value

Wow! Nice, that works. But why does my approach still return nullable?

And: What are the semantics of a "non-nullable" form control? Does this really mean that fields should ALWAYS have a value from the beginning, like default values, or does this only mean that the fields have to be set when the form is submitted?

I'm not sure why formGroup.value returns an object where the typing still includes null | undefined as it should infer the type from the FormGroup definition, but by accessing the controls directly you receive their individual type as defined in your interface. /n
Your second question: I believe that yes the controls must be created with an initial, non-null, value. When moving to typed forms I have exclusively used NonNullableFormBuilder.

Thanks, but many forms start out empty. So they are "semantically" null, because there was no value entered by the user. I would think that in most cases form controls should be nullable with a Validator.Required, because this shows that they can have an empty state in the beginning, during the lifetime of the form, but NOT in the end. Of course in those cases I hit my typing problem again and need an interface like above.

Common misconception there: undefined means a variable has been declared but has not yet been assigned a value, whereas null is an assignment value, meaning that a variable has been declared and given the value of null. I would avoid null in forms where possible.
